# How can I handle spaces in arguments?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, arguments

My app launches and loads the file if I do: `myApp /file:c:\nospaces.asd` from `cmd` but if I do `myApp /file:c:\with spaces.asd` it won't work because the program receives two arguments: `myApp /file:c:\with` and `spaces.asd`.

I know that I can do `myApp "/file:c:\with spaces.asd"` and it'll work like that from `cmd`. However this isn't a good solution because if I double click the `.asd` file (custom extension) (and select launch with my app) then `main` won't be getting the arguments as one line but as two arguments.

How can I go about fixing this issue so that my `main` will receive only one argument when double clicking the file?

Comment: Remove the spaces from your app filename

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes but I can only do that from a command prompt, if the user jsut double clicks the file, then that won't work.

Comment: @FirebladeDan These files can be named by the user and so it could be called anything, spaces should be allowed. Like a microsoft word file, you wouldn't expect it to fail if you saved it with a space in the name

Comment: You may need to modify the registry to make sure command line args are wrapped with quotes. These answers might be helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/361816/pass-command-line-arguments-to-windows-open-with

Comment: Well I would just make my life easy and make spaces illegal in the file creation. Sounds like you've spent enough time on this.

Comment: Why does double-clicking on the .asd file launch myApp?  How did you set up the association?

Comment: @VGR through windows, if you double click an unknown type it'll ask you what program to open with and then I can select my exe from there

Comment: And what is that .exe file?  Is it javaw.exe, or did you use some utility to turn your Java application into a self-contained .exe?

Comment: @MarcBaumbach that link is useful and I think i've got it working now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could join the arguments together if the file is not found. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = joinArgumentsToValidFileName(args);
}

public static String joinArgumentsToValidFileName(String[] args) {
    if(args.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    String fileName = args[0];
    int index = 1;
    while(!new File(fileName).exists() && index < args.length) {
        fileName += " " + args[index];
        index++;
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

This assumes that the first argument (or the arguments) must be the file name. Any additional agruments could be evaluated by remembering the offset index somehow (not included in the code above).

But note: This is a not standard behavior of passing arguments to an application and could lead to cunfusion. So if you find a way to pass a `""` wrapped file name argument, don't do this!

Comment: yes this is a good workaround that I thought of, but it's just a bit too hacky

Comment: Very hacky... Just added a note :-)

Answer (score 0):

Double clicking to launch java would be affected by whats registered in windows related to the same i.e windows registry for jar-file launch command.

These are some similar questions asked on SO you can take a look at:

[Running JAR file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows)

[java can run jar from cmd but not by double clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325676/java-can-run-jar-from-cmd-but-not-by-double-clicking)

They mention the useful part which is ensuring you have the wildcard behind the executable in the registry `c:\...\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %`